# Script runs fine in debug mode but behaving different on running as a simple run

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit4, selenium-ide

I have two list boxes on a page and when I run my selenium script which has to select one value in each of the list boxes and fill some text fields and submit. On submitting selenium clears the last selected value in list box. However, the same thing doesnt happen when I run the same test in debug mode.

Here's my code,

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Question2")).click();
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("olrQuestion2"))).selectByVisibleText("What is your dogs name"); // the list box is accessed
    driver.findElement(By.id("questionTwo5")).click();//the option is selected
    driver.findElement(By.id("olrAnswer2")).sendKeys("dog");//value is input
    //driver.findElement(By.id("olrAnswer2Confirmed")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("olrAnswer2Confirmed")).sendKeys("dog");//Value is input
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.submit_input")).click();//Submit is clicked
```

On clicking submit, the listbox is cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Explicit wait** instead of `Thread.sleep()` and `Implicit waits`.

for example,

> WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); 
>   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input.submit_input")));
>
> driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.submit_input")).click();

Comment: okay use explicit wait like above; it is a good way of testing when you do regression.